"Hit the curb" meaning
In the song "I Had Some Help" by Post Malone and Morgan Wallen, the following verse is found:
You got a lot of nerve, don't you, baby?
I only hit the curb 'cause you made me
You tellin' all your friends that I'm crazy
Like I'm the only one
I've already done some research trying to understand the meaning of the expression "hit the curb" and although I found some results, even with different meanings between them, I'm not sure what the meaning of this expression would be in the song in question. What does this expression really mean in this context?

Urban Dictionary gives three possible idiomatic meanings: 1: to get drunk/high; 2: to engage in prostitution; 3: to leave (especially, to leave an unpleasant situation). Given the context of the song quote in your question, I believe the third definition is the best fit. He's just broken up with his girlfriend, and now she's complaining about him to her friends, so he's defending his action by saying she made him do it - i.e., walk out on their relationship. At least, that's my best guess: I'm not familiar with the song or the expression other than from your question.

Link to the above definitions: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hit%20the%20curb (Warning: #2 is NSFW.) There's also the literal meaning of hitting a curb (i.e., the edge of the sidewalk) with one's car, but that seems like the least likely possibility for the way the phrase is used in your quote.

Because the expression "hit the curb" doesn't have a single, fixed meaning in English, and thus choosing which definition the songwriters intended requires some degree of interpretation, this question may not be the best fit for ELL. Questions that require interpretation or analysis of song lyrics are often considered to be off topic here, since the kind of artistic license used in songs/poetry means that a knowledge of standard English grammar and usage often isn't sufficient to give a correct or meaningful answer.

Agreed. What stands out to me is that whatever the phrase means (and I can guess several possibilities) the lyric is clear: It's all her fault. That's the focus of that line, and in fact the whole verse.

Side note - Irish people, Brits, Aussies, New Zealanders, South Africans hit the kerb.

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for lyrics interpretation in a context where the text was more likely influenced by rhyme / prosody than by peripherally relevant semantics.

Note that a curb/kerb marks the edges of a road/path - obviously a figurative route in the cited context, so you can safely assume it's the same general negative reference as losing one's way, going astray, hitting the rails,...

@QuackE.Duck I've never heard definitions 1 and 2, I think 3 is the most well known and common definition. It's probably related to "hit the road" (as in "Hit the road, Jack, and don't come back...")

I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question that would help ELL. It's about the interpretation of song lyrics which are not necessarily standard English nor advisable for student study. In other words, it's off topic for this site's purpose.
